# How to open password protected file on Mac

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to open password protected file in Mac.
I have found this method so far. But since I am using Mac, win32com doesn't work for me.

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"./Input/file.xls",False, True, None, 'password')
xlCSVWindows = 0x17

workbook.SaveAs(r'C:\file_decrypted.csv', FileFormat = xlCSVWindows, 
                Password = None)
workbook.Close()
```

Does anybody have a way to open excel file on mac, without having to manually intervene?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used Numbers to open an excel password protected file once - whether it still works is a different question...

Comment: Would you please share your approach? The code maybe. Thanks Solar Mike!

Comment: I did not code Numbers... that is an application written by Apple.

Comment: Ahh! Sorry my bad I was totally looking for a python code, so missed your point. I need the python script to handle the files. Not a manual intervention. I have 1000 such files to compile later. Few of which are password protected.

Comment: So is there a solution? If yes can you share your code?